# How can I run Windows cmd in a separate emacs window?

Tags: emacs

**M-x cmd** runs the **cmd**, but upon typing ... well, anything ... I get *"no answer"*.
**How can I get plain old cmd in a separate emacs buffer?** Like the one I would get by typing Win-R cmd?

*p.s. Emacs newbie here ... just playing with it for a bit ... go easy on the flames ...*

Comment: (That's the correct behavior because cmd.exe is only the command interpreter (i.e. like `bash`) and conhost.exe is the thing that actually draws the window (i.e. like `xterm`). To get a new window, use `start.exe`.)

Comment: @billc.cn - I don't really care about the "correct" behaviour, more about the one I want. Is there a way then to get cmd in emacsw32?

Comment: I don't use emacs, but if you run `start`, it should open cmd.exe in a new window by default.

Comment: @billc.cn - Okey, yes, but what good is that? I mean, I know how to get a new cmd window, but I want it inside emacs, not as a separate window.

Answer (score 1):

Try `M-x shell`. A shell within emacs is even better than a command prompt.

Comment: I found "shell", but I need cmd. Some of my stuff depends on cmd behaviour.

Comment: There is also M-x term, though I haven't used it myself, so I don't know if it works on Windows.

Comment: No, I don't seem to have it (asks for an exe to run).

Answer (score 0):

I have defined the following function, which I have put in file "utilities.el".

```
(defun command-shell ()
  "opens a shell which can run programs as if run from cmd.exe from Windows"
  (interactive)
  (let ((explicit-shell-file-name "cmdproxy")
    (shell-file-name "cmdproxy") (comint-dynamic-complete t))
    (shell)))
```

In my initialization file I have

```
(autoload 'command-shell (concat my-lisp-area "utilities.el") "sets up a shell buffer for DOS commands" t)
```

This combination defines a command "command-shell", which initiates a shell buffer in which the shell is "cmd" from MS Window.

In my case cmdproxy.exe is found in "C:\Program Files\emacs-23.3\bin".

My Emacs version is "GNU Emacs 23.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt5.1.2600) of 2011-03-10 on 3249CTO".